Creating tasks in another task in Java
I wrote a function that submits tasks to ExecutorService. This function has a condition if it's true function will call itself to create another task.
private void taskCreator(int v, ExecutorService executor) {
    executor.submit(() -> {
        if (// some condition) {
            taskCreator(u, executor);
        }
    });
}

How can I wait until all the tasks are completed?
I tried to use Future<?> with the method get() but the main thread completed executing before ExecutorService. I also don't know how many tasks will be.

Looks like this will be a recursive invocation till the condition is met.

You can probably try to keep the condition before calling submit
Have you tried Future - isDone method to check if the task is really complete?

You can debug this in an IDE or use Print statements to understand if task was created. At this point you will also know if the programm is going into an uncontrolled recursion

Easiest option based on your code? Get the Future from your call to submit and call get on it. That will prevent taskCreator from returning until the task completes or the thread is interrupted. If that doesn't work for you then please [edit] your question to provide a [mre].

That said, you may want to look into ForkJoinPool and ForkJoinTask (specifically, one of its subclasses). They might fit your use case better.

If you want the first task to wait until its new second task completes, then skip the executor service. Directly execute the new second task, using the first task’s thread. Flow of control returns to the first task only when the second is done.

Designing wise, it's not a good idea recursive creation of tasks. You may end up with memory leaking issues and generally speaking it's a weak choice.
Anyway according to your code there is no Future<> to be returned as long your task seems to perform an action rather than return a result.
You may take advantage of the .join() function you can call on a Task object.
This method call will block the execution of that thread until the Task isn't completed.
To fix your code you need to declare a Task variable using that Runnable you are passing directly to the executor. After the recursive call use the .join().
Eventually you'll also need to call the join on your main thread where the recursion begin so that the trick works.
Still.. You might consider other approaches :).

What is this Task class with a join method that you are talking about? There's no such class in OP's question, and while there are several classes in the Java library that have "Task" in their names, I can't find one that's just called, "Task."

You can't do that. You need to get the Future<?> of all the tasks you want to wait for to complete. But you can't get the Future<?> of child tasks until their parent tasks have completed.
If you try to do this, you will have to wait forever for all tasks to complete and you will likely face the risk of deadlock.
public class ExecutorServiceDemo {

    private static final ExecutorService SERVICE = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    private static final BlockingQueue<Future<?>> QUEUE = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000);

    private static class Task implements Runnable {

        private final int number;

        public Task(int number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Task " + number + " startup");
                if (number < 10) {
                    // Risk of deadlock
                    QUEUE.put(SERVICE.submit(new Task(number + 1000)));
                }
                System.out.println("Task " + number + " shutdown");
            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            QUEUE.put(SERVICE.submit(new Task(index)));
        }
        // Infinitely waiting for completion
        while (true) {
            Future<?> future = QUEUE.take();
            future.get();
        }
    }
}

